# Random based on a given number?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random

I'm recoding in AS3 an old project done with AS2. I have this line in AS2:

```
 randNum = random(quizQuestions.length);
```

How can I do the same with AS3?

Note: quizQuestions.length is the number of Questions.

Thanks in advance,

Sergio

---

Update:

```
var randNum:Number = Math.round(1 + (quizQuestions.length - 1) * Math.random());
```

This wors like a charm.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this formula with AS3 to get random numbers:

```
randNum = min + (max - min) * Math.random();
```

Comment: You've also forgotten to round the result.

Comment: Makes it that much more random! ahahaha.

Comment: Well it's still just as 'random', there are just less possible results :P But in this particular case you need rounding because I assume `randNum` will be used as an index to get a record from `quizQuestions`. With THAT said it's even worth mentioning that you should round *down* to stay in bounds of the array.

Comment: I am not that familiar with `AS3`, so if you want to edit, go ahead and I will confirm.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Here is the final version:

var randNum:Number = Math.round(1 + (quizQuestions.length - 1) * Math.random());

Cheers

Comment: Glad I/We could help!

Answer (score 0):

The same line in AS3 will be

```
randNum = Math.random() * quizQuestions.length;
```

If your `randNum` is not an `int` type, you should use following line:

```
randNum = int( Math.random() * quizQuestions.length );
```

Comment: Don't forget to round that.

Comment: No need if randNum is int type variable.

Comment: That's true, but in your answer it's *not*.

Comment: if it was randNum:int, then even if I assign a Number type variable it will become an int.

Comment: Yes, but in your answer there is no indication that `randNum` is an int.